# can't connect to own python server on vps

Tags: python, server, vps, serversocket

I wrote a server with the socket module and set a public IP and a port, and now I entered everything correctly and I have no syntax errors, but now I can't connect to the server I ran.
Thank you for helping me.

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ip = '102.217.229.10' #for example my public ip address
    port = 4444  #example i selected random port
    s.bind((ip, port))
    s.listen(1)
    print(f'{BLUE} server started on port {port} {RESET}')
    print(f'{BLUE} listening .... {RESET}')
    c, addr = s.accept()

    print(f'{GREEN} {addr} connected to server ... {RESET}')
```

Comment: are you sure you got port 4444 exposed, not blocked by any filters or VPS settings?